# Firebase rooms with limited number of participants

Tags: java, android, real-time, firebase

In [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), creating "rooms" such as for chats is easy, just as documented in their various samples.

For the data structure of the chat, I would use something like this:

```
rooms
    room1
        member_count
        members
            user1
            user2
        messages
            message1
```

But now I would like to create to create a limit on the number of participants per room, say 3 users per chat room.

How can you do this?

In their docs, the one thing that looked most promising was using [transactions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/transactions.html). Can you verify that this is a good way to go? Or is this the wrong approach?

What about a solution like this?

```
Firebase countRef = new Firebase("https://mychat.firebaseIO-demo.com/rooms/room1");
countRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData currentData) {
        int oldMemberCount = currentData.child("member_count").getValue(Integer.class);
        currentData.child("member_count").setValue(oldMemberCount + 1); // try to update member count
        return Transaction.success(currentData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError error, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
        if (error != null || !commited) {
            // rollback value (how? just do nothing?)
        }
        else {
            // transaction has been commited (value has already been saved?)
            currentData.child("members").child(CURRENT_USER_UUID).setValue(CURRENT_USER_NAME); // add user to the members list
        }
    }
});
```

It would be great if you could comment on this approach. Furthermore, one cannot be satisfied in that situation of course if the transaction has failed. The user still wants to join, no matter that there was another user trying to join at the same time. So what do to? Put this code into a function and call the function again in the error case?

**Edit:**

To create a new room with automatically unique ID, one could certainly use [push()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html) on a `Firebase` reference.

But if you want to add members to that room then, the problem described above remains. An alternative solution could be to set users' [priority](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html) in the member list when joining. When setting their priority to the current timestamp, one could then [limit](https://www.firebase.com/docs/queries.html) the member list callbacks to 3 (members). But that doesn't seem to be elegant nor clean.

Comment: Couldn't you just read the value members_count, and if that is lower than 3, then ´join´ else ´abort´?

Comment: No, if two clients tried to join simultaneously, they would both set the members_count to 4 and join. After that, actually 5 clients would be in the room. And this scenario is quite likely in real-time applications, isn't it?

Comment: If you did a check before they connect, and after they are connected you will be fine. Firebase as you know is not 30millisecond real-time. They are really fast but not like 30 milliseconds delay you are talking about. If you that kind of fast, you need a server, which does the logic and not use Firebase.
But one solution that could work is that you make a securityrule, which prohibits writing if `val().children().length === 2`. That would properly work.

Comment: You don't need 30ms real-time data in order to see conflicts there. With Firebase, the client does always store a local copy of the dataset, which is then automatically synchronized with the server version. I'm not making this example up, but Firebase does explicitly hint to that problem and advise to use transactions in their docs, as I've posted: https://www.firebase.com/docs/transactions.html This is definitely the way to go. The question was only whether the implementation that I proposed is okay, as it is a bit more complex than the simple example Firebase has given in their docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed (and relatively small) number of participants per room, it'd be best to use transactions. However, it might be best to create well-named objects for each person in a chat room, for example:

```
/rooms
  /<roomid, generated by push()>
    /users
      one: null
      two: null
      three: null
```

Joining a room would look like (code in JavaScript, please convert to Java as appropriate);

```js
var userid = "myuserid";
var ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/rooms/<roomid>/users");
ref.transaction(function(users) {
  if (!users.one) {
    // Claim slot 1
    users.one = userid;
    return users;
  } else if (!users.two) {
    // Claim slot 2
    users.two = userid;
    return users;
  } else if (!users.three) {
    // Claim slot 3
    users.three = userid;
    return users;
  }
  // Room is full, abort the transaction.
  return;
}, function(err, committed, snapshot) {
  if (committed && !err) {
    // Joined room successfully.
  } else {
    // Could not join room because it was full.
  }
});
```

Firebase will automatically call the transaction function if it fails to commit the value to the server. In addition to the code above, you'll also need to implement some security rules that prevent users from claiming a slot that's already taken:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "rooms": {
      "$roomid": {
        "users": {
          "$slot": {
            ".write": "!data.exists()"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can upload these rules via Forge, the graphical debugger for your Firebase and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I meant :) But why is the security rule necessary? From the docs about transactions (if `nobody else has modified it, the transaction is successful and your completion callback is called. Else, if there was a conflict, the Firebase client retrieves the new value and re-runs your update function`), I understood that you can just use transactions without security rules, because they alone make sure nobody else modified the data. And if someone did, you first get the new value and can check again if the room is empty. Is this wrong?

Comment: I'm asking because it would be very good, of course, if a user could leave the channel again and someone else could claim his slot. That would be possible without a security rule. But with your security rule, you could not remove yourself from the slot because `write` privilege is gone as soon as data is there, right?

Comment: That's right, the security rule is only in place to prevent a rogue client from taking someone else's spot. But, as you point out, it also means you can't remove yourself from the room. You can drop the security rule to allow for that, or if you're logging your users in via some auth mechanism, you can change the rule to "!data.exists() || auth.id == data.val()" to ensure only the user who has claimed a spot can remove themselves.