# Why is onChildChanged() firing before onComplete() when using transactions in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

With Firebase for Android, I'm using the following data structure for a chat room with a limited number of slots:

```
/rooms
  /<roomid, generated by push()>
    /users
      one: null
      two: null
      three: null
```

For my clients to take one of the slots (`one` to `three`), I'm using the following code [as provided here (JavaScript version)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18324795/89818):

```js
var userid = "myuserid";
var ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/rooms/<roomid>/users");
ref.transaction(function(users) {
  if (!users.one) {
    // Claim slot 1
    users.one = userid;
    return users;
  } else if (!users.two) {
    // Claim slot 2
    users.two = userid;
    return users;
  } else if (!users.three) {
    // Claim slot 3
    users.three = userid;
    return users;
  }
  // Room is full, abort the transaction.
  return;
}, function(err, committed, snapshot) {
  if (committed && !err) {
    // Joined room successfully.
  } else {
    // Could not join room because it was full.
  }
});
```

After some testing, I found that this does not work. Am I right with the following two assumptions that explain why it's not working?

1. In `runTransaction(...)` (Android) or `transaction(...)` (JavaScript), you have to set the optional parameter `fireLocalEvents` (Android) or `applyLocally` (JavaScript) to `false` because otherwise you will receive events from the transaction although it might not be successful.
2. Even with `fireLocalEvents` (Android) or `applyLocally` (JavaScript) set to `false`, the events for `onChildChanged(...)` on that reference will fire *before* your transaction returns successfully in `onComplete(...)`. Is this intended behaviour?

What that means for this special case is that I will be notified about the chat room being full (in `ChildEventListener.onChildChanged(...)`) *before* I get to know that *I myself* am the one who got the last slot (in `Transaction.Handler.onComplete(...)`).

Let's assume that, if the room is full ...

- and I got a slot there, some code is executed and something new is launched.
- and I didn't get any of the slots, I just want to hide the room from the list (as it is not available anymore).

If I want to do that, I have to move the complete logic for that to `ChildEventListener.onChildChanged(...)`, because that's where I will receive the event first, right? Otherwise, the room will be hidden before I get to know that I was the one who got the last slot there.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems intuitive that onchildchanged would logically fire before oncomplete.

Comment: @danny117 Why? You are informed about data changes by the server before the server actually tells you that your transaction, which caused the changes, successfully completed? Had I turned local events on in the transaction handler, I would agree. But as it is, not really. That's what the `fireLocalEvents` flag is for.

Comment: onComplete seems like it would be ehh complete?

Comment: @danny117 So yes, the data should not update until the transaction has *completed*. It seems you agree.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually one of the components that makes Firebase an amazing app and saves you tons of coding. To understand why this is in your benefit, we need to back for a second and talk about latency compensation and offline functionality.

If you've ever written an app that provides real-time features, then you've run into the spaghetti mess of connection errors and temporary outages. It leads to tons of if/else/then logic to retry things once the connection is restored.

Firebase abstracts all of this complexity so that your app works the same offline as it works when online. You can still listen for events, set/save/update data, and continue on as if online. When the connection is restored, the events are applied.

Similarly, when you do a set() operation locally, it's very slow to wait for the server to reply before applying the changes locally. Again, this leads to lots of if/else logic for latency compensation--tracking when you make changes locally and showing them immediately so the user doesn't feel like the app is unresponsive.

Firebase again handles these complexities internally. Since 99.9% of your write ops in production are going to succeed, as bugs are generally responsible for sending invalid content, we just apply the change locally by firing the correct events. Then, if the server replies with that extreme edge case, we redact the change by applying another event that corrects the status.

So in summary, Firebase data is eventually consistent when you make a change. Thus, you're going to see the local event immediately, and this is a good thing. If something goes wrong in the process, you'll see a second event to correct the data, probably a few hundred milliseconds later.

Comment: Thanks! I have understood the concept of Firebase but the problem is a different one. As you can see in the numbered list of my two questions or assumptions, I have turned off local events for the transaction. At least that should be what the parameter is for, right? The problem is that both the local and the remove event are firing before the transaction completes. So even without local events, the sync'd event from the server arrives before I know that my transaction has been successfully committed. This may obviously not always be what you want. Is this behaviour intended or a bug?

Comment: Hi Marco, I didn't fully understand the question here. I'll leave this up for context even though it doesn't directly answer the question. I think what we're seeing is that your event is firing after the transaction completes, but before your onComplete callback. I wonder how we could verify this?

Comment: Well, it's easy to reproduce the transaction + child event listener thing. When you do this, you will see that the `onChildChanged(...)` does *always* fire *before* the `onComplete(...)` callback. Any chance this could be changed if it is like you said, i.e. if the transaction really completes before the child event is fired. I mean, if it does, why should the order of the callbacks be the other way round? Or any idea for a workaround?